# How does usermod allow you to bypass sudo?

Tags: permissions, sudo, security

My team had a show-n-tell recently and I presented my findings on [Docker](https://www.docker.com). I explained how you can install Docker with:

```
curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

I then explained that, with this installation, you need to prefix all Docker commands with `sudo` (e.g. `sudo docker info`), unless you run:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker myUser
```

Once you do this, you can just run, say, `docker info`.

Another junior engineer asked me how this `usermod` command worked, and I explained it as I understand Linux users/groups:

- All the Docker binaries are installed on the system belonging to a group named `docker`
- Since `myUser` is not by default a member of `docker`, it has no rwx permissions to do anything with the Docker binaries
- So the solution is to either use `sudo` which gives you root permission for the given command, or to give `myUser` membership to the `docker` group

When I explained it this way a senior engineer very abruptly told me I was wrong and that "*it's a little more complicated than that.*"

So I ask: am I misunderstanding Linux's security model here, and is the senior engineer correct? If so, what am I missing (and what the heck is "so complicated")? Or am I correct, in which case, can someone point me to some solid documentation to prove it?

Comment: `man -Hfirefox usermod` or `man usermod`

Comment: Thanks @mchid (+1) - I'm not asking for how `usermod` works, I'm asking i my explanation to my co-worker was factually correct or not.

Comment: it *looks* like it appends the user to that group in the file /etc/group. If I'm not mistaken, it's pretty much the same as adduser in which case I would agree with you but I'm not fully sure . https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2012/11/msg01225.html

Comment: maybe you could ask the senior engineer to explain *why* or what makes it more complicated so you can understand it better

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are talking about how secure Linux is and the Vulnerability it can have yes. If I am understanding what you are asking clearly enough the answer for you is yes and my explanation is that Linux regardless of the distribution to my knowledge can get viruses like any other operating system depending what you install or not. Take flash player for examples even on windows it gives many security flaws on the operating system making it more vulnerable than before when it was just out of the box

If you ran linux with no desktop and all that other fancy privilege it would if I am not mistaken be more secure than with all our favorite apps and such
I don't know if my answer helped but I hope this did

Comment: Thanks @Goat (+1) - but I think you missed my question. I'm simply asking if my explanation of how `sudo usermod -aG docker myUser` works is correct. Thoughts?

Comment: I think your right on that part don't let that guy get to you from what I have learned in most linux based communities is that things are tough especially when they see you in person

Comment: -1 I don't see how this answer makes sense wrt to the question.

Comment: This answer isn't quite accurate, and vulnerabilities in code/software is not quite related to users/groups.

Answer (score 4):

> All the Docker binaries are installed on the system belonging to a group named docker

Incorrect. The `docker` binary is owned by `root:root`:

```
$ stat `which docker`
  File: ‘/usr/bin/docker’
  Size: 16296881    Blocks: 31832      IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fc00h/64512d    Inode: 143202      Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
```

> Since myUser is not by default a member of docker, it has no rwx permissions to do anything with the Docker binaries

The binaries are readable and executable by everyone.

> So the solution is to either use sudo which gives you root permission for the given command, or to give myUser membership to the docker group

The Docker service uses a socket to listen for commands. The socket is typically:

- located at `/var/run/docker.sock`
- owned by `root:docker`
- and group-writable, but not readable or writeable by others:

For example:

```
$ stat /var/run/docker.sock
  File: ‘/var/run/docker.sock’
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   socket
Device: 10h/16d Inode: 13619       Links: 1
Access: (0660/srw-rw----)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (  997/  docker)
```

*That* is why being a member of the `docker` group allows you to run `docker` commands.

Note that you can specify which group should be used as a parameter to the `docker` service. From `man docker`:

```
   -G, --group=""
 Group  to assign the unix socket specified by -H when running in dae‐
   mon mode.
 use '' (the empty string) to disable setting of a group.  Default  is
   docker.
```

So, it doesn't *have* to be `docker`, but it is `docker` by default.